# Select top 3 largest number from list in R using order( )?

Tags: r, sorting, matrix, dataframe

Image I have a list L like

```
    L = 
    "a", "b", "c", "d", "e"
    {3,   4,   5,   2,   1}
```

I want to select the top 2 or 3 largest value from the list.
For instance, I want top 3 from the list, that means I want "c", "b", "a", and correspondingly, the values are 5, 4, 3, which are the largest 3 values.

I was told I can use order() function, but I dont know how.

Answer (score 2):

```
L=c(3,   4,   5,   2,   1)
names(L)=letters[1:5]
head(L[order(-L)],3)
# c b a 
# 5 4 3
```

Comment: or just `rev(order(L))[1:3]`